# How to format named params into strings dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, string, format

I have an array with parameters - for each parameter I have a name and a value.
Is there a way to format it dynamically into a string with a placeholders?

array:

```
[{'name': "a", 'value': "123"}, {'name': "b", 'value': "456"}]
```

string: `"blabla {a}"`

required result: `"blabla 123"`

Comment: Is there a reason why your data is in that format? Instead of a list of dictionaries you should just store the name/value pairs in a dict.

Comment: Note: Python uses the name `list`, not `array`, for the mutable sequence data structure. There is a [separate `array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) supporting a single numeric type for each value only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your string input already uses valid [string formatting placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), all you need to do is convert your existing data structure to a dictonary mapping names to values:

```
template_values = {d['name']: d['value'] for d in list_of_dictionaries}
```

then apply that dictionary to your template strings with the `**mapping` call syntax to the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) on the template string:

```
result = template_string.format(**template_values)
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_dictionaries = [{'name': "a", 'value': "123"}, {'name': "b", 'value': "456"}]
>>> template_string = "blabla {a}"
>>> template_values = {d['name']: d['value'] for d in list_of_dictionaries}
>>> template_values
{'a': '123', 'b': '456'}
>>> template_string.format(**template_values)
'blabla 123'
```